# React state array gives null error in rendor

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript

I am calling API which emit JSON  I am calling this promise api function in **componentDidMount** and setState and then call this in render method but it always emit null error.

Please help me

**interface for location**

```
export interface ILocation {
  info: Info;
  options: Options;
  results: Result[];
}

interface Result {
  providedLocation: ProvidedLocation;
  locations: Location[];
}

interface Location {
  street: string;
  adminArea6: string;
  adminArea6Type: string;
  adminArea5: string;
  adminArea5Type: string;
  adminArea4: string;
  adminArea4Type: string;
  adminArea3: string;
  adminArea3Type: string;
  adminArea1: string;
  adminArea1Type: string;
  postalCode: string;
  geocodeQualityCode: string;
  geocodeQuality: string;
  dragPoint: boolean;
  sideOfStreet: string;
  linkId: string;
  unknownInput: string;
  type: string;
  latLng: LatLng;
  displayLatLng: LatLng;
  mapUrl: string;
}

interface ProvidedLocation {
  latLng: LatLng;
}

interface LatLng {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}

interface Options {
  maxResults: number;
  thumbMaps: boolean;
  ignoreLatLngInput: boolean;
}

interface Info {
  statuscode: number;
  copyright: Copyright;
  messages: any[];
}

interface Copyright {
  text: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  imageAltText: string;
}
```

**IWeatherStates**

```
export interface IWeatherStates {
  Locations: ILocation
}
```

**getLocation**

```
private getLocation(latitudes: number, longitude: number): Promise<ILocation> {

    let promise: Promise<ILocation> = new Promise<ILocation>((resolve, reject) => {
      let query = `${this.LIST_API_ENDPOINT}/location/${latitudes},${longitude}`
      this.props.httpClient.get(query, HttpClient.configurations.v1, this.httpClientOptions).then((rawResponse: HttpClientResponse) => {
        return rawResponse.json()
      }).then((jsonResponse) => {
        resolve(jsonResponse)
      })
    })
    return promise
  }
}
```

**componentDidMount**

```
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.getLocation(29.378586, 47.990341).then((location: ILocation) => {
      this.setState({
        Locations: location
      })
    })
  }
```

**construction**

```
constructor(props: IWeatherProps) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      Locations: null
    }
  }
```

**render which give error **

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IWeatherProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.weather}>
       {this.state.Locations.results[0].locations[0].adminArea5}
      </div>
    )
}
```

> > {this.state.Locations.results[0].locations[0].adminArea5}
> >     results give null error

Comment: How do you expect to get index 0 from null?

Comment: add checks if locations is null, render "No Locations loaded" etc

Comment: in componentDidMount if i put console.log it gives output

Comment: put console in render function and you will see null

Comment: yes why it is so !!

Comment: because your initial value is null and it will take time to get updated by api data

Comment: then how can I solve it !!

Comment: You are setting the Location property in a promise in the componentDidMount method. The value for Location is not set until that promise receives some data, therefore on first render, `this.state.Location` will be null. This is reason for your null error. as @ZohaibIjaz already mentioned, add a null check in your render for Location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check to avoid `null` value

```js
public render(): React.ReactElement<IWeatherProps> {
    const { Locations } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className={styles.weather}>
       {Locations ? Locations.results[0].locations[0].adminArea5 : 'Not loaded'}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Dear, I explained earlier, if your code will try to do `something[0]` where something is `null` it will break. So you need to check if your variable is null or not. If null then do something else

Comment: can we make function to check null and do output.

Comment: I tried but it did not works. I pass two parameter first any and another string. So first is null than empty other wise another string but as result is null it did not run :(

Comment: I don't know much TypeScript